# Jquery Deffered Exception In moodle with datatable

Tags: php, datatables, moodle

[image]
For all whom will have eyes on this , we have a serious problem here jquery-datatables not working sometimes it stuck like the screenshot above , we don't know why when we refresh the page everything is working perfect .we tried to re-arrange scripts , but the result is the same so from 10 times working perfect , it stuck one time has any one seen something like that before in moodle version 3.5

thanks

Comment: I think the method to use DataTables plugin is `.dataTable`, not `.deepsight_datatable`.

Comment: @entoniperez , in normal ways Yup , but in my case and in moodle in particular it's deepsight_datatable , the problem that it's working perfect , but in sometimes returns this error which is weird